# Jquery Detect Change when Updated by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I know this might appear paradoxical but I'm trying to work out how to detect a change on a text input when the value is updated by jquery.

During the user using the page my javascript does this:

```
$('#LicenseOwnerId').val(company.Id);
```

What I want to do is react to this value being set and execute another function.

So far I've tried the following methods:

```
var obj = document.getElementById('LicenseOwnerId');
obj.onChange = function () {
    alert('select changed!');
};
```

And I've tried this:

```
$('#LicenseOwnerId').bind('change input propertychange', function(event) {
    alert('select changed!');
});
```

And I've also tried this:

```
$('#LicenseOwnerId').change(function () {
    alert('select changed!');
});
```

None of these seem to get fired when the value is updated and I cannot think of any other methods to try and hook this up.  What is the correct way (if any) to wire this up?

I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible and consequently is also cross browser safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as easy as this:

```
$('#LicenseOwnerId').val(company.Id).trigger('change');
```

using

```
$('#LicenseOwnerId').change(function () {
    alert('select changed!');
});
```

There is no other way (without modifying jquery core methods), you have to trigger the event yourself.

Comment: Holy Half-Wit Batman ... !! `<slaps forehead>` Kevin B, thank you.  I'll be over there in the dunce corner if you need me.